# Adding a tag to aggregated data in influxdb

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I'm having trouble understanding how to add tags to data series as I do `SELECT INTO` queries. I have an Influxdb of the [NYTimes COVID dataset](https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data) where I've used the `cases` and `deaths` fields as `fields` and the `state` and `county` information as tags.

I can aggregate data from neighboring counties in a query like this:

```
SELECT sum("cases") AS "cases" FROM "ny_covid"."autogen"."value" WHERE ("state"='Pennsylvania') AND ("county"='Philadelphia' OR "county"='Delaware') GROUP BY time(1d) FILL(null)
```

This works perfectly. But I want to save this aggregated data into a new database for doing other queries. Which I can do like this:

```
SELECT sum("cases") AS "cases" INTO "new_covid"."autogen"."value" FROM "ny_covid"."autogen"."value" WHERE ("state"='Pennsylvania') AND ("county"='Philadelphia' OR "county"='Delaware') GROUP BY time(1d) FILL(null)
```

My question is, how do I add a tag like `location=Philly` to the data I've just inserted into the `new_covid` database? Because, I'd like to do a few other location level aggregations and it seems like the `tag` is the way to keep these values distinct.

```
SELECT sum("cases") AS "cases" INTO "new_covid"."autogen"."value" FROM "ny_covid"."autogen"."value" WHERE ("state"='Pennsylvania') AND ("county"='Dauphin' OR "county"='Lancaster') GROUP BY time(1d) FILL(null)
```

All of the searching I've done has just been about using the tags in queries or preserving them when copying across databases. But I haven't been able to find anything about attaching tags in `SELECT INTO` type statements.

Comment: Do you really need to create new tag? Why you can't reuse existing tags `state,county`?

Comment: @JanGaraj Because I would like to add the tag for the `sum` of 6 counties as a new area in the new database. That way I can pull them out of the `new_covid` database by tag and distinguish it from the 7 county `sum` around Pittsburg or 8 around Harrisburg. I also don't know how I would transfer the tags from the previous DB into the new one anyway. This is also a general question: "How do you add tags to data inserted with a `SELECT INTO` statement"?

Comment: ok, then you need to do it on the app/own code level: `select data; add new tag to data; insert data;`. Use your favorite language with InfluxDB support (e.g. python) and code it.

Comment: Is it really the answer that there is no way to add tags while doing `SELECT INTO` statements? The only way to add tags is to pull data out of one database and then re-insert it again. Conversely, the only way to distinguish aggregations in `SELECT INTO` statements is to send them to distinct `fields`?

Comment: Nope, you have also other options. Such as: join InfluxDB, persuade team that this is important feature, so it will be implemented/fork source code and implement it on your own. InfluxQL is not SQL and I don't think that this feature is widely used in the timeseries world. Use better DB, which will fit your needs. Maybe InfluxDB 2.0 (still beta) will be better - it supports multi-data store world - you can connect also relational DB = maybe you will be able to use it as a "temp" storage for data transformation, where you can use good old SQL.

Comment: Touché @JanGaraj I guess I have been using it as more of a "time-series analysis" tool instead of its more intended use-case as a time-series storing tool.

Comment: I have had also idea that idea InfluxDB is the best tool until I got SQL selects with conditional CASE expressions from devs. I switched to SQL (Redshift in my case) and devs are happy, because now they can do all their classic SQL magic.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get the required functionality by using [TICKscript language](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/tick/introduction/) which is complimentary part of InfluxDB within the TICK stack.
However that requires to use [Kapacitor](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/introduction/) and [Chronograf](https://docs.influxdata.com/chronograf/v1.8/) in addition to InfluxDB itself.

The Kapacitor will performs tasks written on TICKscript language to manipulate the data. The Chronograf provides a Web UI to configure InfluxDB and Kapacitor.

Find the TICKscript task example for InfluxQL queries from your question:

```js
var b1 = batch
    |query('''
    SELECT sum("cases") AS "cases" 
    FROM "ny_covid"."autogen"."value" 
    WHERE ("state"='Pennsylvania') AND ("county"='Philadelphia' OR "county"='Delaware') )
    ''')
        .offset(1d)
        .period(1d)
        .cron('@midnight')
        .groupBy(time(1d))
    // Write the transformed data to InfluxDB
    |influxDBOut()
        .database('new_covid')
        .retentionPolicy('autogen')
        .measurement('value')
        .tag('location', 'Philly')

var b2 = batch
    |query('''
    SELECT sum("cases") AS "cases" 
    FROM "ny_covid"."autogen"."value" 
    WHERE ("state"='Pennsylvania') AND ("county"='Dauphin' OR "county"='Lancaster')
    ''')
        .offset(1d)
        .period(1d)
        .cron('@midnight')
        .groupBy(time(1d))
    // Write the transformed data to InfluxDB
    |influxDBOut()
        .database('new_covid')
        .retentionPolicy('autogen')
        .measurement('value')
        .tag('location', 'Dauphy')
```

Also that is not one way to get such result. As well you could examine the [`stream` approach](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/nodes/stream_node/)  instead of [`batch` used](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/nodes/query_node) above.

All you need to run this code is create new task for kapacitor:

Chronograf-> Alerting tab -> Manage tasks -> "+Write TICKscript" button in the TICKscripts section.

To get the full TICKstack environment you may use [offitial sandbox on dockers](https://github.com/influxdata/sandbox)